# How to view debug logs in IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I am new to IBM Bluemix. I have created new IBM Mobile Foundation service to the dashboard. I wish to view the console logs for my application.

I referred the following link for logs in Bluemix -
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/10/bluemix-logging-options/

To view logs using Bluemix, the doc says follow the steps -

Login to Bluemix -> Click Dashboard -> Click on your application -> Click on Files and Logs:

The expected screen is as below.
[image]

I try to follow the steps  -
Bluemix Login -> Dashboard -> My_Foundation_Service
But i can't find "Files and Logs" option anywhere.

[image]

Please can someone show me how i can view server debug logs in IBM Bluemix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an instance of **Mobile Foundation Service**, it creates a `Cloud Foundry Application` which hosts the Mobile Foundation runtime as a `Liberty Application`.

It seems that you have navigated to the `Services` section in the Bluemix dashboard.

In 'Cloud Foundry Apps' section, you will see an application. In your case the app name should be similar to **MobileFoundationmu-Server**.
Select that app and you should see `Logs` section to get the logs.

Comment: Yes, basically you only get logs for Apps, not Services.  Services are shared and you cannot access their backend logs.  But when your App sends a request to a Service, that and the response will generally be in your App's logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cloudfoundry cli and the bluemix cli then you can just type in cf logs APP_NAME in cmd.